# Is there a way to move/reset the search pointer in preg_match_all()?

Tags: php, regex

Take the following example,

```
preg_match_all("/(^|-)[a-z]+(-|$)/i", "foo-bar-moo", $matches);
```

This (correctly) returns the following matches,

```
foo-
-moo
```

However, I need to generate the following matches output,

```
foo-
-bar-
-moo
```

Is there actually a way to do this? Say for example by moving the search pointer back one character after a match?

My only other idea is to put this in a `while()` loop, removing matches on each loop, until all matches are found.

Thanks.

**Edit**: I tried to simplify my issue to make the question clearer, but in doing so I seem to have misrepresented what my issue actually was. Apologies.

Basically I needed a way to match a word in a string where the character immediately preceding or the character immediately following were a certain character, but at the same time without capturing these leading and trailing characters in the match.

I was under the impression you couldn't do this, so instead I decided to capture the leading/trailing characters and remove them myself. This led me to the issue above.

As Tim Pietzcker pointed out, what I actually needed was [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

So for my example above, the solution is as follows,

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|-)[a-z]+(?=-|$)/', "foo-bar-moo", $result);
```

And it outputs,

```
foo
bar
moo
```

Thanks again for the answers and the help.

Comment: Could you just make the hyphens optional (I think this is the syntax)? (^|-)?[a-z]+(-|$)?

Comment: No can do, I need to pick up the `-`'s if they match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookaround and put capturing groups in the lookaround expressions. This allows you to do it in a single `preg_match_all()` call and still capture the `-`es if present:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=(^|-))([a-z]+)(?=(-|$))/', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($match = 0; $match < count($result); $match++) {
    echo $result[$match][1] . $result[$match][2] . $result[$match][3];
}
```

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gent. The example in my question was quite abstract from my actual problem (sorry), and lookaround expressions are exactly what I need to solve my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use the `offset` parameter in `preg_match`.  Start at 0, get the first match of `-*[a-z]-*`.  Take the `matchOffset + matchLength - #dashesAtEnd` and use that as the offset into the next `preg_match` call.

Comment: That's an option. However, I've got a big piece of content under test and a _long_ generated regular expression. Ideally I'd love to pass something into `preg_match_all()` so I only need to run it once for performance.

Comment: @Stephen, I assume preg_match_all would have to do almost the same thing, except not decrement the current offset.  Are you certain it's a performance problem?

Comment: @agent-j: I'll do some benchmarks and see if running it multiple times really does impact. Cheers for the suggestion though. Hope I can use it.

Comment: @agent-j: So, for strings < ~100 characters, running `preg_match_all()` was fastest, even as much as 80% decrease in time taken. But for longer strings, running `preg_match()` multiple times was faster. I ran `preg_match()` 5 times as example. Because we're talking milliseconds anyway, I'm happy to live with the `preg_match()`. Cheers again.

Comment: Another note is `preg_match()` obviously gets slower the more times it needs to run. You need to determine which is the best approach, either looping with `preg_match()` or looping with `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
preg_match_all("/(^|-)([a-z])+(-|$)/i", "foo-bar-moo", $matches);
```

You'll get [foo,bar,moo].

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't do anything different to the regular expression in my question and gives the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Thought you needed:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo-
    [1] => -bar-
    [2] => -moo
)
```

But as I can see from your updated question, this should work as well:

```
preg_match_all("/(?-)[a-z]+(?-)/i", "foo-bar-moo", $matches);

echo $matches[0];

Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => moo
)
```